# Component making infinite calls to server when clicked on route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

A component of my overall react app also renders a component upon clicking a linked item of my component. When it is clicked it makes many calls (infinite) to my database for information to populate the new component.

I've attempted to axios instead of plain fetch in the calls. I've attempted to limit the render times within set state.

Sidebar Component

```
<Router>
    <div id = "left-sidebar">
    <h3> Previous Posts </h3>
    { this.sidebar_feed() }
    <Route path='/post/:title' component={Page} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

Function of Page component that is called when mounted.

```
getPost = () => {
    let postSearchTitle = this.props.match.params.title;
    console.log(this.state.text);
      fetch("/api/getPost/" + postSearchTitle)
         .then(data => data.json())
         .then(response => this.setState({
         title: response.post.title,
         text: response.post.text.split("\n")
        }));
    };
```

Server side api

```
router.get("/getPost/:title", function(req, res) {
    let title  = req.params.title;
    PostModel.findOne({title: title}, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) return console.log('error: ' + err);
        return res.json({post: resp});
    });
    console.log("Attempted " + ++localCount);
});
```

When you click on a post, the page should rerender and be post should be present. So far it rerenders many times and doesn't load actual text.

EDIT:
Lifecycle code

```
componentDidMount() {
     this.getPost();
     if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
      let interval = setInterval(this.getPost, 1000);
      this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
     }
}
```

Comment: What lifecycle method or action triggers `getPost`? If you're doing it in `render` or `componentDidUpdate` you'll end up in an infinite loop because you are updating your state on success. If you're calling `getPost` from `componentDidMount` or from your constructor, you should be safe.

Comment: I updated it with the code that calls getPost. It is indeed called by ```componentDidMount```

Comment: It looks like your code is calling `getPost` every second via `setInterval`. Is that what you're seeing? Is your intention to call `getPost` every second?

Comment: It looks like that, so would setting it for a larger interval be better or maybe no interval at all?

Comment: That’s completely up to you and the needs of your component. If you don’t need to keep calling it, you can just get rid of the interval.

Comment: @DonBrody the removal of ```setInterval``` ended up stopping the repeated calls.